Background Service in Android does not run
could you please help why my service does not run?
Android Studio compileSdk = 34, minSdk = 29, targetSdk = 34
I there changes in some Android policy?
Stackoverflow is asking for some details but I do not know what to add to the question.
updated:
Manifest is added
Again "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView text = findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (text.getText().toString().equals("Started")) {
                    text.setText("Stoped");
                    stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,service.class));
                } else {
                    text.setText("Started");
                    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,service.class));
                }

            }
        });
    }
}



public class service extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ToneGenerator toneGen1 = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
        toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP,150);

        return START_STICKY;

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup = "true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ServiceTry1"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>






Can you share your AndroidManifest.xml? What do you mean exactly when you say it does not run? Anything in the logs?

@tomerpacific Done )

You are missing the <service> element in the manifest. This is covered in the documentation.
